# Expandable listView row item not showing Serially

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Here is my Data resource for the list item. The Problem is occurred that list View item not added synchronously. Are anyone can say? why this occurred? Are any issues in my code?

### Data Pump:

```
    public class SemesterDataPump {
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> semesterListDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> firstSemester = new ArrayList<>();
    firstSemester.add("Computer Programming Concept");
    firstSemester.add("Electrical Device");
    firstSemester.add("Deferential and Integration Calculus");
    firstSemester.add("Physics ");

    List<String> secondSemester = new ArrayList<>();
    secondSemester.add("Electronics ");
    secondSemester.add("English");
    secondSemester.add("Structure Programming Language ");

    List<String> thirdSemester = new ArrayList<>();
    thirdSemester.add("Bangladesh Studies ");
    thirdSemester.add("DAta Structure");
    thirdSemester.add("Digital logical Design");
    thirdSemester.add("Public Speaking");

   .........

    semesterListDetails.put("1st Semester",firstSemester);
    semesterListDetails.put("2nd Semester",secondSemester);
    semesterListDetails.put("3rd Semester",thirdSemester);
```

...........

```
    return semesterListDetails;
}
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkmqr.png)

Comment: Try change HashMap to LinkedHashMap. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeh! thank you. Using LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap, it's working well now this time.

Answer (score 1):

use this may help you :

```
 Collections.sort(semesterListDetails);
```

Comment: Before return statement put @
mohammadReza Abiri's  answer code

Comment: Here is my code: here semesterListDetails is Hashmap thats will not possible to apply in the Collections.
public class SemesterDataPump {
    public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> semesterListDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> firstSemester = new ArrayList<>();
        firstSemester.add("Computer Programming Concept");

Comment: sort your String lists : Collections.sort(firstSemester);
Collections.sort(twelveSemester);